# Assimp loads vertices, but model is not getting displayed

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, assimp

**IDE:** xcode

**System:** MacOS

#### What I'm trying to do

My [project [repo]](https://github.com/BlkPingu/GLFW_SolarSystem/tree/005/model_loading/CG) is at the point where I successfully made a [skybox [tutorial link]](https://github.com/SonarSystems/Modern-OpenGL-Tutorials/tree/master/%5BADVANCED%20OPENGL%5D/%5B17%5D%20Cubemap:Skybox) work, but I'm struggling with [assimp's model loading [tutorial link]](https://github.com/SonarSystems/Modern-OpenGL-Tutorials/tree/master/%5BMODEL%20LOADING%5D/%5B16%5D%20Model%20Class).

#### The problem

I don't receive any errors. The model is just not loading into the window, even though I added [`cout << vertices.data() << endl;` [GitHub line link]](https://github.com/BlkPingu/GLFW_SolarSystem/blob/b068906210fb44b129559d557bab0848152c44ec/CG/src/Model.h#L165) at the respective line in the [`model.h` [GitHub line link]](https://github.com/BlkPingu/GLFW_SolarSystem/blob/b068906210fb44b129559d557bab0848152c44ec/CG/src/Model.h#L1), after it get's initialized in [`main.cpp` [GitHub line link]](http://%20%20%20%20Model%20ourModel(%20%22res/models/earth_2.5k_combined_png_optimised_export.obj%22%20);)  which is printing `0x106e6b000`, so the models vertices are loading.

However, the window remains empty, apart from the background color.
[In the tutorial [YouTube video link with timestamp]](https://youtu.be/yQx_pMsYqzU?t=3247), which I followed faithfully, it's working.

#### What I'm trying to achieve:

I'm trying to render the model `nanosuit.obj`, which is proven to be red in. `ourModel.Draw( shader );`should draw it, but doesn't or it's not being displayed.
For some reason it's not being displayed, despite no errors that data can't be found or exceptions triggered.

I would love to give a MCVE, but the code it very much interconnected, hence the GitHub links.

As far as I can say this should draw the model, unless it complains.

```
// Draw the loaded model
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate( model, glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.75f, 0.0f ) ); // Translate it down a bit so it's at the center of the scene
        model = glm::scale( model, glm::vec3( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f ) ); // It's a bit too big for our scene, so scale it down
        glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( shader.Program, "model" ), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( model ) );
        ourModel.Draw( shader );
```

Stuff I tried:

- Rotating the camera to check if the model rendered outside of my FOV
- playing around with scaling
- loading other `.obj`s
- printing variables that are being passed around, only to see that indeed the model is being loaded, just not displayed

[image]

I'm trying not to code dump, hence the line links. Feel free to tell me if you want code snippets. I'm kind of lost here as for why this is happening.

#### Edit:

@Botje suggested I try these things:

1. [`modelLoading.frag` [repo, line link]](https://github.com/BlkPingu/GLFW_SolarSystem/blob/005/model_loading/CG/src/res/shaders/modelLoading.frag) to apply red color instead of the textures to try to minimize the risk of something being wrong with the models textures. Was ineffective. Still no model.

```
     void main( )
        {
            //color = vec4( texture( texture_diffuse, TexCoords ));
            color = vec4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
```

2. In `model.h`, edited [`cout << vertices.size() << endl;` [repo, line link]](https://github.com/BlkPingu/GLFW_SolarSystem/blob/1ba7dcba6adad10f5a319cfa5ec3d996256339ec/CG/src/Model.h#L165) prints, which is correct for the `nanosuit.obj` model from the tutorial. I had a planet in there, which was not part of the tutorial, therefore the `0x106e6b000` from previously. I now get for `vertices.size()`:

> 156 15222 19350 78 6804 7248 8316

So the model is definitely loading, just not rendering. The problem must me somewhere after the model loading but before the rendering.

Comment: I would not rely on `vertices.data()` being NULL for an empty array. Better to check `.size()`

Comment: To rule out as many other factors as possible, start by hacking your fragment shader to assign a flat color instead of reading from the texture. `color = vec4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` If that produces a red shape on the screen, I think your issue may be in your fragment shader linkage: `modelLoading.frag` needs `texture_diffuse` while Mesh.h line 87 assigns `texture_diffuse1` (see the " + number" there.)

Comment: @Botje added an edit to the equestion. i applied both suggestions, but so far nothing is showing in the window. I also threw the "nanosuit.obj" from the tutorial back in, wich consists of multiple parts. you can see it in the repos res/models . still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Model was never initialised. The tutorial was pre 2018, which is when GLM went away from auto initialising.

In the snippet I posted was the error.

It's supposed to be:

```
// Draw the loaded model
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

Instead of:

```
// Draw the loaded model
glm::mat4 model;
```

#### What happend?

My GLM version is `0.9.9.3`, while the tutorials is most certainly pre [`0.9.9.0`](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases/tag/0.9.9.0), the version they changed it.

Noted, a lot of tutorials use this code.

The one [I worked with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQx_pMsYqzU) didn't [change it either](https://github.com/SonarSystems/Modern-OpenGL-Tutorials/blob/228ac36f91c14f9c42d5cfb56ff559c712f3ac50/%5BMODEL%20LOADING%5D/%5B16%5D%20Model%20Class/main.cpp#L124).

> **You can check your GLM version** in xcode by clicking on the project in
>   your file browser, selecting the App in the Tartget list and then
>
> Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths
>
> Double click to open the list.

Comment: Nah, GLM *used to* default-init vectors and matrices.  [They stopped in min-2018 with 0.9.9.0](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases/tag/0.9.9.0): "Removed default initialization, use `GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT` to restore the old behavior"

Comment: @genpfault I see a model now. I don't see a model without this. What would I have to change in order to have it auto load? Higher GLM version? Current version is 0.9.9.3 ( as per header search path `/usr/local/Cellar/glm/0.9.9.3/include/`).

Comment: I was referring to the "The tutorial was just garbage for not doing it." statement: when the tutorial was written/last updated GLM would default-init things.  If you built the tutorial against a pre-2018 GLM I suspect it would still work.

Comment: Ooooooh i'm so sorry, yes, you are absolutely right. They went back to explicit initialising. Edited my answer. Thanks for the history lesson!

Comment: I have the same problem but I already had this code and this is not the issue